# Add-Migration command has an error in my .NET 6 project

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project and created it using .NET 6.

I used the `Add-Migration` command before adding some `DbSet` in my `DbContext`, it worked correctly and made migration files for me.

Today add a new `DbSet` to my `DbContext` after that used the `Add-Migration` command but I get an error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'HospitalNetDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I get some information from this link but I can't solve my problem.

Some people suggested using contractor without parameter in `DbContext` class, but when I add this contractor to `DbContext` class and after that, I used the `Add-Migration` command, I get a new error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

After this error I added a new constructor same as below but my problem still persists:

```
public HospitalNetDbContext(DbContextOptions<HospitalNetDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

More information about my project is connection string defined into the app settings file and in startup file using below code for set connection string to `DbContext` instead of add into overriding `OnConfiguring` method in the `DbContext` class.

```
services.AddDbContext<HospitalNetDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HospitalNetDb")));
```

Comment: I solved this problem by added below code into OnConfiguring method => `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"MyConnectionStrig");`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the issue for me was that I hadn't specified the startup project and target project.

The class I was using that inherited from DbContext was in a data access project separate from the startup project, and I think it meant that without specifying the startup project the configuration in program.cs hadn't run when it was trying to initialise the context class and that's why it failed. When I ran it like this it worked:

```
Add-Migration -Name MyNewMigration -StartupProject {startup project name} -Project {project containing HospitalNetDbContext}
```

This page was helpful for me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#target-and-startup-project.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I have 2 constructors in DbContext, one empty and one with DbContextOptions. Also checkout to override the OnConfiguring method in your DbContext.